# Active Directory Group inside Group and Sharepoint Site Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

I have create GroupB inside GroupA in active directory and give permission to GroupA in sharepoint site.GroupA contains UserA and GroupB contains UserB. If i logged in using UserA than everything works fine but if i logged in using UserB than it will give error message like 'Sorry,this site hasn't been share with you'.Why i am not able to view any pages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that nested AD group is supported for SharePoint 2010/2013, however it is not recommended by some Microsoft groups. I would say don't use AD group nesting.
For more detailed issue please check this blog, very good information. 
http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2013/04/nested-ad-groups-support-issues-in.html